# Is it possible to execute same tags multiple times in maven command for cucumber project on different tag position?

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have 5 scenarios and those tags are
@UserAddSaveButton, @UserEditSaveButton, @UserAddSaveContinueButton, @UserEditSaveContinueButton, @UserDelete

Now I want to execute all 5 scenario in below sequence
@UserAddSaveButton, @UserEditSaveButton, @UserDelete, @UserAddSaveContinueButton, @UserEditSaveContinueButton, @UserDelete

See **@UserDelete** tag is used twice but when I execute Maven command it's executed only once and at last position is not working.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. This really seems like you are asking too much of tags and hooks. Hooks execute in the hook order defined on them. Not in the order they are put in front of a scenario. And hooks are only executed once, not as many times as you tag the scenario. I’d recommend you reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't achieve this with a single TestRunner file.

Here are my 2 ways:

**Solution#1:**

1. Create 3 TestRunner files
2. In your testng.xml file, create 4 `<suite>` tags that contains TestRunner test classes in this order - TestRunner1, TestRunner2, TestRunner3 and TestRunner2
3. TestRunner1 to execute '@UserAddSaveButton, @UserEditSaveButton' tags
4. TestRunner2 to execute '@UserDelete' tag
5. TestRunner3 to execute '@UserAddSaveContinueButton, @UserEditSaveContinueButton' tags

Now run your tests (as mvn test or from testng.xml), deletion scenario will be executed as mentioned in testng.xml order by TestRunner2 suite#2 and suite#4 as you expected.

**Solution#2:**

1. Make your deletion tests/steps in single function
2. Create conditional hooks

> ```
> @After("@UserEditSaveButton or @UserEditSaveContinueButton")
> public void deletionSteps(){
> // your deletion steps goes here OR 
> // call your deletion step from here
> }
> ```

3. Just have single TestRunner file for tags '@UserAddSaveButton, @UserEditSaveButton, @UserAddSaveContinueButton, @UserEditSaveContinueButton'
4. The conditional @After hook will take care of performing the deletion (You can remove the deletion scenario from your feature file)

However, non-technical users will not know that deletion is performed after the execution of @UserEditSaveButton OR @UserEditSaveContinueButton scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Bhuvanesh. Solution 1 is preferable. :)